# “Python has stopped working” - openalpr on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows-10-desktop, openalpr

I'm working with [OpenALPR](https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/wiki/Integrating-OpenALPR) with Python scripts. The input image from argparse arguments, whenever I run from command prompt, it is giving output and displaying a dailogue box with error

> "python has stopped working"

Why it is happening could anyone help?

If try to debug using mcsv2017 it shows

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF8BC68AA2C (ntdll.dll) in python3.exe:
>   0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters:
>   0x00007FF8BC6E3180).

Comment: I think this has to do with the code may we see it?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue: Do not download the current github repository. Use the source code of the released version from here: https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/releases/

and run python setup.py install in src\bindings\python folder. here you go